# Auth synchronization between aws-amplify and @aws-amplify/ui-react

Tags: reactjs, authentication, aws-amplify

I'm migrating my application from `aws-amplify-react` to the new `@aws-amplify/ui-react`.

On app load in a browser that the user has already signed-in with I am getting a discrepancy in authentication state between aws-amplify and the `useAuthenticator` hook in @aws-amplify/ui-react.

```
import { useAuthenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import { Authenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react'; 
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
```

on app load if I do:

```
Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
  .then((user) => {
    console.log('AUTHENTICATED');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
  });
 };

const { user } = useAuthenticator((context) => [context.user]);
const { route } = useAuthenticator((context) => [context.route]);

console.log(route, user)
```

I see that `Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()` reports AUTHENTICATED but `route === 'idle'`  and `user === null`.

If I render an `<Authenticator />` component then the latter updates to 'authenticated' (without the signin UI actually being displayed).

Note that I'm not wrapping my entire app in `<Authenticator />` but `<Authenticator.Provider />`  and trying to only render `<Authenticator />` in my /login (react-router) route since I have a mix of protected and unprotected routes and a mix of roll requirements.

How am I meant to keep these two states synchronized?

Comment: This is a known issue and is being tracked here https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-ui/issues/1497. One workaround is to use `Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser` as mentioned, other is https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-ui/issues/1497#issuecomment-1064292547.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty long thread and it seems to have gone in a few directions, so hopefully this is still related.

#### Backstory:

I'm using AWS Amplify with React Native.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-amplify/ui-react-native
I want to customize the UI for my sign in and signup experiences.

#### What worked but without a custom UI

I discovered that using the "out of the box" UI like this:

```
 <Authenticator>
  {children}
</Authenticator>
```

Allowed me to create a user, login with that user and upon login in the view would re-render to reveal the `{children}`.

#### Custom Sign In UI doesn't re-render...

Great the previous approach allowed me to login, but it used AWS Amplify's UI, and desire more control.  So I started writing this:

```
 <Authenticator
components={{
      SignIn: props => {
        return <MySignIn {...props} />;
      },
      SignUp: props => {
        return <MySignUp {...props} />;
      },
    }}
    Header={MyHeader}
    Footer={Footer}
>
  {children}
</Authenticator>
```

Although my UI looked pretty, whenever I invoked `const res = await signIn({ username, password });` within MySignIn component on press of the "Sign In" button, the UI would not re-render.  It would not reveal my `{children}`, like it did before with the out of the box UI.

#### Solution

It appears that after authenticating, the user is not picked up and stored within the Authenticator, and thus not passed into the children.  Even though the `authStatus` does change to "Authenticated" it doesn't appear to also store the user.  And my {children} components rely on that user data.

The only way I was able to get around this is by doing the following.

First I needed to update my Authentication file:

```
<Authenticator.Provider>
    <>
      {authStatus === 'unauthenticated' && (
        <Authenticator
          components={{
            SignIn: props => {
              return <MySignIn {...props} />;
            },
            SignUp: props => {
              return <MySignUp {...props} />;
            },
          }}
          Header={MyHeader}
          Footer={Footer}
        >
          {children}
        </Authenticator>
      )}
      {authStatus === 'authenticated' && children}
  </>
</Authenticator.Provider>
```

Then inside the component that is in the `{children}`, in my case `<Wrapper>` I had to add this:

```
import { fetchAuthSession } from 'aws-amplify/auth';
const { authStatus } = useAuthenticator();
const [user, setUser] = React.useState<AuthUser | undefined>(undefined);
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchSession = async () => {
    const res = await fetchAuthSession();
    setUser(res.tokens);
  };
  fetchSession();
}, [authStatus]);
```

This properly retrieved the user after login and set it into the user state.

I had hoped instead to not have to do this.  Instead I assumed that in Wrapper I could get the user like this `const { user, authStatus } = useAuthenticator();` and not have to run the `fetchAuthSession()` method.

If there is an alternative approach I'm very open to using it.  This feels like a work around because using the AWS Amplify "out of the box" UI does in fact trigger the re-render and reveal the children.  Not sure why my custom UI approach with `signIn()` doesnt work..

#### Other findings

If you look at the compiled code within node_module OR here https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-amplify/ui-react-native?activeTab=code you will find `/@aws-amplify/ui-react-native/dist/Authenticator/Authenticator.js` and within this file you can see these lines of code:

```
....
const { Component, props } = useAuthenticatorRoute({ components });
const typedFields = getRouteTypedFields({ fields, route });
const isAuthenticatedRoute = route === 'authenticated' || route === 'signOut';
if (isAuthenticatedRoute) {
    return children ? <>{children}</> : null;
}
return (<SafeAreaProvider>
  <Container>
    {Header ? <Header /> : null}
    <InnerContainer>
      <Component {...props} fields={typedFields}/>
    </InnerContainer>
    {Footer ? <Footer /> : null}
  </Container>
</SafeAreaProvider>);
...
```

As you can see, the children should be rendered when the route `isAuthenticatedRoute = route === 'authenticated' || route === 'signOut'` but this doesn't seem to happen (not sure why).